# threejs makePerspective method has been removed or changed

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

in an older version of threejs, you could do this:

```
camera.projectionMatrix = THREE.Matrix4.makePerspective( fov, aspect, 1, 1100 );
```

this is now throwing an error:

```
has no method 'makePerspective'
```

What has this been replaced with and how do I call it?

The documentation still notes that this method exists, and I found it in `THREE.Matrix4.prototype.makePerspective`, but it doesn't work if I call it there.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a prototype method like a static one. It needs to be called on a Matrix4 instance. You could try:

```
camera.projectionMatrix = (new THREE.Matrix4()).makePerspective( fov, aspect, 1, 1100 );
```